# Filling Random numbers in array: ERROR: cannot implicitly type int to int[]

Tags: c#

I'm trying to fill random numbers in a jagged array, but i'm getting error at this line:

```
arr[size] = randNum.Next(Min, Max);
```

ERROR: cannot implicitly type int to int[]

Here is full code:

```
Random randNum = new Random();
            int Min = 1;
            int Max = 100;

            int rows;
            int size;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of rows of jagged array:");
            rows = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            // Declare the array of two elements:
            int[][] arr = new int[rows][];

            for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the size of" +rows +" :");
                size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                for (int j = 0; j <= size; j++)
                {
                    arr[j] = new int[size];
                    int n = 0;
                    while (n < size)
                    {
                        arr[size] = randNum.Next(Min, Max);
                    }

                }
            }
```

Can any one help in this regard?

Comment: _arr[i][n] = randNum.Next(Min, Max);n++_

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the first dimension of the array (the rows) and ask the size of the array that you want to be saved in the current row, after that, you could dimension the array and fill the elements of the array stored in the current row. You have an internal for loop not needed because the filling is done in the while loop

```
// Loop till rows - 1
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the size for the array in the " + i + " row:");
    size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    arr[i] = new int[size];
    int n = 0;
    while (n < size)
    {
       arr[i][n] = randNum.Next(Min, Max);
       n++;
    }
}
```